# SwingWorker.cancel(true); is not working in java

Tags: java, swing, concurrency, swingworker

This is a part of my java code, in this I am trying to terminate the thread before its completion using SwingWorker.cancel(true); method but this is not working, so please help.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;


public class A extends SwingWorker<Void,Void> {

    JProgressBar p = new JProgressBar(0,100);
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    static A a;

    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        a = new A();
        a.execute();
    }

    public Void doInBackground() {
        f.add(p);
        f.setSize(500,100);
        f.setVisible(true);

        for(int i=0; i<101; i++) {
            p.setValue(i);
            try{Thread.sleep(30);}catch(Exception e){}
            if(i==50)
                a.cancel(true);
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Look at your code, you are catching the `InterruptedException` that `sleep` might throw, ignoring it and continuing like nothing happened. So why are you surprised that cancellation does not work?

Answer (score 4):

Handling cancelation is actually your responsibility - it's not an inherent property of the swingworker. From the documentation: ["The task must cooperate with its own cancellation ...](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/cancel.html). There are two ways to do this:

- By terminating when it receives an interrupt. This procedures is described in Interrupts in Concurrency.
- By invoking SwingWorker.isCancelled at short intervals. This method returns true if cancel has been invoked for this SwingWorker.

For your problem, the second is clearly applicable. Every for iteration, check if the task has been canceled. If so, return. In this code I've moved the cancellation to the main thread, since a task telling itself to cancel doesn't make that much sense (just return instead), but canceling in the working thread should be fine.

```
public class A extends SwingWorker<Void,Void> {

  JProgressBar p = new JProgressBar(0,100);
  JFrame f = new JFrame();
  static A a;

  public static void main(String arg[]) throws InterruptedException {
      a = new A();
      a.execute();
      Thread.sleep(2000);
      System.out.println(a.cancel(true));
  }

  public Void doInBackground() {
      f.add(p);
      f.setSize(500,100);
      f.setVisible(true);
      f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

      for(int i=0; i<101; i++) {
        if(isCancelled())
          return null;
        System.out.println(i);
        p.setValue(i);
        try{Thread.sleep(30);}catch(Exception e){}           
      }
      return null;
  }

}
```

Comment: Actually the *first* way is applicable here as the operation taking the longest time is `Thread.sleep()` which will already stop early by throwing an `InterruptedException` on interruption. So the information about a cancellation comes “for free” when you just replace the `catch(Exception e){}` by something meaningful. Then, there is no need to poll `isCancelled()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: use `MyStringWorker` class by creating an object.
For example:

```
MyStringWorker sw = new MystringWorker(args).execute();
```

Within try block use:

```
sw.cancel(true)
```

> refer for more:
>   http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#isCancelled--